# Runing Ejabber sever in Mac OSX

Tags: ios, swift, macos, xmpp, ejabberd

Ejabber 16.12
OS X El Capitan (version - 10.11.3)

I am following this link to configure Ejabber server for iOS application:

- http://shubhank101.github.io/iOSAndroidChaosOverFlow/2016/08/Chat-Application-Using-XMPP-Swift-Tutorial

But when I try to run Ejabber server I am getting following error:

> (ejabberd@localhost)1> bin/ejabberdctl: line 214: 12196 Illegal
>   instruction: 4  $EXEC_CMD "$CMD"

**Screenshot :** 
[image]

After that if I try to Register new user then on Terminal I am unable to type any further command .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally able to solve this issue :

We need to open port 5280 , 5266 , 5222, 5266 for proper working of Ejabberd Server locally

Permission issue showing such error .Hope it helps other too.